# How do I tell PROC FREQ to only display the tables which have missing values?

Tags: sas

I have a data set with many variables - many of which are character valued. I have the following code to count the number of missing values for each variable:

```
proc format;
 value $missfmt ' '='Missing' other='Not Missing';
 value  missfmt  . ='Missing' other='Not Missing';
run;


proc freq data=dataname; 
format _CHAR_ $missfmt.; /* apply format for the duration of this PROC */
tables _CHAR_ / missing missprint nocum nopercent;
format _NUMERIC_ missfmt.;
tables _NUMERIC_ / missing missprint nocum nopercent;
run;
```

However, this results in a huge output (300 page pdf if I print to pdf) with 90% of the variables having no missing values. How do I tell PROC FREQ to only display the tables which have missing values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can identify which variables have a missing value from the NLEVELS option in PROC FREQ.  So my process would be to create a dataset that just held the variables with missing values, then store them in a macro variable so the following PROC FREQ can be run against them only.
Here is the code to do that.

```
/* set up dummy dataset */
data have;
set sashelp.class;
if _n_ in (10,13) then call missing(age,sex);
run;

/* create dataset that holds variables with missing values */
ods select nlevels;
ods output nlevels=miss_vars (where=(nmisslevels>0));
ods noresults;
proc freq data=have nlevels;
run;
ods results;

/* store names in a macro variable */
proc sql noprint;
select tablevar into :missvar separated by ' '
from miss_vars;
quit;

proc format;
 value $missfmt ' '='Missing' other='Not Missing';
 value  missfmt  . ='Missing' other='Not Missing';
run;

proc freq data=have (keep=&missvar.); 
format _CHAR_ $missfmt.; /* apply format for the duration of this PROC */
tables _CHAR_ / missing missprint nocum nopercent;
format _NUMERIC_ missfmt.;
tables _NUMERIC_ / missing missprint nocum nopercent;
run;
```

Comment: If I would also like to omit all tables with all missing values how do I do this? nmisslevels counts the types of missing values. I'm finding it difficult because I can't count the number of missing values in proc freq and because I can't use proc means with my many character valued variables.

Comment: just change the where clause to (where=(nmisslevels>0 and nnonmisslevels>0))

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I would like to omit all tables with variables that contain exclusively missing values. Let's say I have 300 observations. I would like to omit tables for variables that have 300 missing values.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear.  If you amend the where clause for the nlevels output table as I suggested, this will give you what you are asking for

Answer (score 1):

This one removes all blank columns:

```
%macro removeblanks(dataset,output);
/* create dataset that holds variables with missing values */
ods select nlevels;
ods output nlevels=miss_vars (where=(nmisslevels>0 and nnonmisslevels=0));
ods noresults;
proc freq data=&dataset. nlevels;
run;

/* store names in a macro variable */
proc sql noprint;
select tablevar into :missvar separated by ' '
from miss_vars;
quit;

data &output.;
set &dataset.(drop=&missvar.);
run;

%mend removeblanks;`
```